# How to not include newlines in strip-export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I'm using the following snippet

```
#+NAME: save-file
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results silent :var filename="filename" plt="plt" :exports none
return f"\nfname = 'assets/' + filename + '.png'\nplt.savefig(fname)\nfname"
#+END_SRC
```

which I include in src blocks like so:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var fig=1 filename="some-filename" :noweb strip-export :results file :session t :exports both :cache yes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(1, 1)

<<save-file("filename", "plt")>>
#+END_SRC
```

My issue is that `save-file` adds some extra newlines in export which I would rather omit. How to overcome this?